# Trigger in Oracle: No data found

Tags: oracle

Please check my code, I seldom use trigger with AFTER clause, thanks so much:

```
set serveroutput on;
create or replace trigger tvideo_2 after insert on video for each row
declare 
pragma autonomous_transaction;
v_title video.title%type; /* Declare a variable to check title that contain '18+' */
begin
select title into v_title from video where video.videoid=:new.videoid;
if v_title like '%18+%' then
update video
set age=18
where videoid=:new.videoid;
dbms_output.put_line('Video '||:new.videoid||' has been updated age to 18+');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Video '||:new.videoid||' is not 18+!');
end if;
end;
/
insert into video values('V5', '18+', 240, 19);
VIDEO properties: (videoid, title, duration, age)
```

Comment: This is not the best use of a trigger. You are using an autonomous transaction to get around the mutating trigger error but this adds the possibility of other issues.  DBMS_output will not show anything when called from a trigger.  Why not use a before insert to set the age?

Comment: I would guess that you want to use a before insert or update trigger, that you want to use `:new.title` rather than selecting from `video`, and that you want to modify the `:new.title` rather than doing an `update` on `video`.  When you have an error, though, it would make much more sense to include the error rather than hoping that we can guess what the error is (and exactly what behavior you want).  Formatting your code with reasonable indentation would also be nice.

Comment: If I create a data that contains 'V5', it will work okay (I must drop videoido is primary key, no any constraints). I often use trigger with before clause for checking inserted row and call raise_app_error. But in this case, you must insert a row then the trigger will check title and update if title contains 18+, else print no 'is not 18+' - that means after trigger (the requirement from Oracle course: Practice-exam. I have already completed it and it can't run...). Sorry for my bad English. xD

Comment: Why can't you check it before insert? What you've said doesn't mean it has to be after insert.

Comment: This is requirement from Practice-exam, the teacher highlight the word AFTER...
To Justin Cave:
I just follow step by step in the requirement of Oracle's Practice-Exam from teacher. He asks me to check title then update age if it contains '+18' and print a message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pragma autonomous_transaction` means that the trigger cannot see the row that has just been inserted and which cause it to be fired.

When you removed the primary key and pre-inserted a record with the same ID, it's *that* row that will be updated by your trigger, not the new one you are inserting - so it still won't do what you want, and duplicating the PK value isn't sensible anyway.

If you have to do this as an `after insert` trigger then you can remove the `for each row`, which avoids the mutating table issue you're presumably trying to avoid, but then you have to query the whole table to find rows to update:

```
create or replace trigger tvideo_2 after insert on video
begin
  update video
  set age = 18
  where title like '%18+%'
  and age != 18;
end;
/
```

Or if you want to print a message:

```
create or replace trigger tvideo_2 after insert on video
begin
  for rec in (
    select videoid, title
    from video
    where title like '%18+%'
    and age != 18
  )
  loop
    update video
    set age = 18
    where video.videoid = rec.videoid;
    dbms_output.put_line('Video '||rec.videoid||' has been updated age to 18+');
  end loop;
end;
/
```

But using `dbms_output` in a trigger, or really in any stored PL/SQL, isn't a good idea - if the client session that does the insert doesn't look at the output buffer than that message is lost, and it's likely there will nothing (or nobody) to see it anyway.

You could also use an explicit cursor with `for update` and then `update .. where current of`.

Either way you're having to query the whole table, which isn't very efficient - you're checking all existing rows every time you insert a new one, instead of just checking that single new value. A trigger isn't really suitable to do that much work - even if it only actually updates a single row (or none!) it has to query everything for *every* insert. That isn't going to scale very well.

There are other way to avoid the mutating table issue but anything is going to be a hack. The sensible way to do this is with a before-insert row level trigger:

```
create or replace trigger tvideo_2 before insert on video for each row
begin
  if :new.title like '%18+%' then
    :new.age := 18;
    dbms_output.put_line('Video '||:new.videoid||' has been updated age to 18+');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('Video '||:new.videoid||' is not 18+!');
  end if;
end;
/
```

(with the same caveat about using `dbms_output`) but that seems to be forbidden for some reason.

Comment: It is better to ask (good) questions here so the knowledge can be shared. Plus there are a lot of other people here who know much more than I do. I learn more than I teach...

Comment: Okay, I understood! May you explain more about the differences between `AFTER` and `BEFORE` trigger?  And I often send a data to variable when using `BEFORE` trigger. Replace the code at beginning with `AFTER` clause = `BEFORE for each row`. Why the select statement `select title into v_title from video where videoid=:new.videoid;` has no data though `:new.videoid='V5'`?

Comment: Because the row hasn't been created in the table yet - you're querying **before** the insert actually happens. The `:new` pseudorecord contains what *will be* inserted. In an `AFTER` trigger the insert has already happened (but hasn't been committed). And in an  `AFTER for each row` trigger `:new` contains what *has already been* inserted - which is why you can't modify it any more.

Comment: Yeah, I have understood about the affect of `:new` variable. But I don't understand why the teacher highlights word `after`, maybe I will ask him later. And If must use after trigger level following the requirement, is anyway to complete this trigger suitable with `IF` clause to print "OK" else "NOT OK" or we must use 2 `for` loop: 1 for `in` and for `not in`? I will read about how to avoid mutating table carefully. And last, you make me confusing when using `after` or `before`. May you give me a simple example to explain more clearly? Thanks for your time so much.

Comment: Yes, ask your teacher why they specified after. [Read more in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#CIHEJCFA).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will read and practice more. If I need more assistance, I will PM you later. Good day for you!